# How to debug ncurses ？

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I wanna learn something from ncurses, so that I can use assembly to write some simple functions to draw graphics.

For example, when I step into `initscr`, then I'm right here `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6`, I can't see any c code. Do you have some any ways to solve this problem?

I use below commands to install ncurses!

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.2.tar.gz

tar xvzf ncurses-6.2.tar.gz

cd ...

./configure --with-shared --with-normal --with-debug --enable-overwrite

make

sudo make install
```

Comment: Seems you linked with system libncurses.so but wanted to do it with your own built libncurses.so.

Comment: @ks1322 There is no `libncurses.so` in my system, the `libncurses.so` is myself install from source code!

Comment: Where did you install your own build of `ncurses` (I would typically expect it to default to something like `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/lib64`)?  `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6` looks like a pre-existing 'system' build to me.

Comment: @G.M I saw the [commands](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/master/INSTALL)

Comment: @G.M. I'm not sure `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6`, I have nerver installed ncurses before.

Comment: @G.M need linker `libncurses_g.a`, then can see c code in gdb.

Comment: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6` was probably installed out of the box in your OS, many ncurses apps depend on it. They would not work without `libncurses.so` installed.

Comment: Looks like OP's using Debian (or Ubuntu), which already have usable development packages for ncurses.  Overwriting the system's ncurses libraries doesn't work well for most people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need linker `libncurses_g.a`

`gcc -g ... -o ... /usr/lib/libncurses_g.a`

Answer (score 0):

```
./configure ...
make
sudo make install
```

99% of the time this installs to `/usr/local`.

`/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` are normally consulted before the usual `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` when *compiling and linking*. However `/usr/local` is completely ignored when loading shared libraries at run time. You need to do something special in order to accommodate this.

There are several ways to do so.

1. Add `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib` to your link command.
2. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to something that contains `/usr/local/lib`.
3. Add `/usr/local/lib` to your `/etc/ld.so.conf` (to be done with caution).

Comment: It doesn't default to `/usr/local` on OP's platform.

Answer (score -1):

Note that basically all Linux terminal emulators support Unicode (using UTF-8) by default, as well as [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences).

So, if you wanted to print a small red double-walled rectangle around the bright green letter "B" in the upper left corner, your program would simply write the following string (in C or assembly notation, i.e. the double quotes are not part of the string contents):

```
"\033[s\033[1;1H\033[0;31m╔═╗\033[0m\033[2;1H\033[0;31m║\033[1;32mB\033[0;31m║\033[0m\033[3;1H\033[0;31m╚═╝\033[0m\033[u"
```

where the two bytes (`27,91` = `\033[`) comprise the control sequence introducer, CSI.

Do remember that `write` syscall is allowed to return a short count, especially when writing to a tty (terminal-like device).  If the return value is positive but smaller than the length of the string, you need to advance the pointer to the data by that amount, subtract the return value from the length, and do the syscall again, until it returns either the desired length or a value less than 1. (0 should not occur, and negative values are errno error codes.)

What ncurses does, is support such codes in their various forms for basically all terminal-like devices, detects the correct one to be used via the `TERM` environment variable, and provides a lot of useful abstractions (via helper functions, like windows and such).  But the above, UTF-8 and ANSI escape codes, works in the majority of cases, and is a viable *minimal* implementation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.